# why I can't get my alertdialog.builder to show() on my screen

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I am trying to get a number of cards to pop up using alertdialog.builder. Even though I did .create().show(); the dialog does not show on my screen. I'm not sure what is causing this problem.

I have marked the place where I am getting nothing in the comments.

Java Code:

```
ImageView image_questionmark= new ImageView(this);

final ImageView image_pass = new ImageView(this);
final ImageView image_youpay = new ImageView(this);

image_questionmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.card_questionmark);
image_pass.setImageResource(R.drawable.card_pass);
image_youpay.setImageResource(R.drawable.card_youpay);

AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PayActivity.this);
for(int i=0; i<people; i++) {
    /*PASS*/
    if(array[i] == 0) {
        dialog.setView(image_questionmark);
        dialog.setPositiveButton("FLIP", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(PayActivity.this)
                        .setView(image_pass)
                        .setPositiveButton("NEXT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                finish(); /*move on to next value in array*/
                            }
                        }).create().show(); /*HERE: Nothing showed on my screen when running debugger...*/
            }
        });
        dialog.create().show();
        /*If not the first card, show previous card*/
        if(i!=0) {
            dialog.setNegativeButton("PREVIOUS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            i--; /*return to previous value in array*/
        } /*First card*/
        else {
            dialog.setNegativeButton("PREVIOUS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No previous card", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }/*YOU PAY*/
    else {
        dialog.setView(image_questionmark);
        dialog.setPositiveButton("FLIP", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(PayActivity.this)
                        .setView(image_youpay)
                        .setPositiveButton("NEXT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                finish(); /*move on to next value in array*/
                            }
                        }).create().show();
            }
        });
        dialog.create().show();
        /*If not the first card, show previous card*/
        if(i!=0) {
            dialog.setNegativeButton("PREVIOUS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            i--; /*return to previous value in array*/
        } /*First card*/
        else {
            dialog.setNegativeButton("PREVIOUS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No previous card", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I did not try your code.But you can try it like -
**First initilise your image object then assign to another final variable.**
I think it will work.

```
ImageView image_pas1 = new ImageView(this);
    final ImageView image_youpay = new ImageView(this);

image_questionmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.card_questionmark);
image_pass1.setImageResource(R.drawable.card_pass);
image_youpay.setImageResource(R.drawable.card_youpay);
final ImageView image_pass=image_pass;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `LayoutParams` for your `ImageView` in order to know how to draw itself. Maybe something like this:

```
image_questionmark.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, // width
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); // height
```

And do this as well for your other 2 `ImageViews`

Comment: When I add this the 'LayoutParams' turns red and says that I have to import a class. Is RadioGroup.LayoutParams correct??

Comment: @awefawe: Try LinearLayout.LayoutParams instead.

Comment: It should, but looking at your code it's a mess. How big is "people" array and you try to show the same dialog multiple times, I think you will need a new Dialog for each one. You should rethink your logic.

Comment: Oh, this is just a part of my code. 'people' is received from the user. Running the debugger, I thought that this part was what was causing the error..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Dialogs need

```
buildervariablename.create();
```

only.
Second, every single Dialog has to be in a seperate class, like this:

```
public class TestDialog extends DialogFragment
{
// Put your dialog code in here
}
```

And then you just call your dialog there, where it is needed. Inside another method, or even another dialog, by using the following:

```
DialogFragment fragment = new TestDialog();
fragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"testdialog");
```

Hope this helped you, if you have further questions, just comment this answer.